# How proguard can skip some reserved names as mapping result

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am developing a gradle plugin. It generates a source java file after proguard based on the mapping.txt. The content looks like following.

```
public class bmdb {

  private static Map<Class<?>, Injector<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();

  static {
      try {
        map.put(a.a.b.c.class, new a.a.b.d());

      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  public static Map<Class<?>, Injector<Object>> a() {
    return map;
  }
}
```

And this java file will be compiled to a class file. However, sometimes the mapped result would be java key words, like `a.a.for.class`, `a.a.int.class`. And the compilation would fail.

So I wonder if proguard has any option which can exclude some words for the mapping result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found proguard does not support such configuration.

And I use following workround:
1. I write a string array containing Java key words like following:
`String[] keyWords = ["do", "if", ...];`
2. I would check the proguard result if it is in the above array. If NO, the normal `new abc()` will be used, and If YES, the reflection `Class.forName("for")` will be used.

So the result might be like following:

```
map.put(a.a.b.c.class, new d());
map.put(a.a.b.d.class, Class.forName("for").newInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom obfuscation dictionary for class names like that:

```
-classobfuscationdictionary dict.txt
```

The file should a simple text file containing valid characters/strings to be used for obfuscation, example:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

You might still end up with reserved words, but if you leave all vowels out, it should work pretty well I think.